# How to get git repository URL on a subfolder

Tags: shell

I have following folder structure:

```
FolderA
-FolderA1 (child of FolderA), and 
-FolderA2 (child of FolderA)
```

Now, Folder A1 and A2 are git repositories. I am writing a script to get the git repository URL of BOTH the folders when I am at the level of Folder.

I tried something like:

```
cd FolderA

git remote -v | awk -F ' ' '{ print $2 }' | sort -u | cd FolderA1

git remote -v FolderA1\ | awk -F ' ' '{ print $2 }' | sort -u
```

But this does not seems to work. Any idea how can I get the URL for FolderA1 / Folder A2 ?

Thanks in advance,
RKS

Comment: The spec is unclear as-written. Should the output have the URLs bare? List each URL next to the directory? ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd do it something like this (requires bash 4 for associative array support):

```
get_subdir_urls() {
  local oldwd subdir url idx
  [[ $1 ]] && { oldwd=$PWD; cd "$1"; }
  for subdir in */.git; do
    (
     declare -A urls
     cd "${subdir%.git}" && \
       while read _ url _; do
         urls[$url]="${subdir%.git}"
       done < <(git remote -v)
     for idx in "${!urls[@]}"; do
       printf '%s\t%s\n' "${urls[$idx]}" "$idx"
     done
    )
  done
  [[ $1 ]] && cd "$oldwd"
}

# usage:
get_subdir_urls FolderA
```

Comment: This worked for me:

    get_subdir_urls() {
    local oldwd subdir url idx
    [[ $1 ]] && { oldwd=$PWD; cd "$1"; }
    declare -a urls
    i=0
  
    for subdir in */.git; do
    (
     cd "${subdir%.git}" && \
     gitPath=`git remote -v | awk -F ' ' '{ print $2 }' | sort -u`
        urls[i]=$gitPath
        i=$((i+1))
     for idx in "${!urls[@]}"; do
       printf '%s\t%s\n' "${urls[$idx]}"
     done
    )
    done
    [[ $1 ]] && cd "$oldwd"
    }

Comment: @RKS It's hard to read your changes there -- but if you're using `i` as an integer counter, that's a pretty questionable way to do things; you could just use a regular array, rather than an associative one, with `urls+=( "$gitPath" )`, and take out `i` altogether. The advantage using an associative array gives you is free deduplication, with no need for `sort -u`; your changes throw that away. Also, I wish you'd describe your spec more clearly -- right now, it's hard to know _why_ the original proposal wasn't exactly what you wanted.